# Adobe Flex 3: can I get TTF/OTF system fonts and embed at runtime?

Tags: flex3, adobe

Adobe Flex 3: can I get TTF/OTF system fonts and embed at runtime?

Hi,

I'm a Stack Overflow noob so please go easy on me.
I've searched all day and found dozens of tutorial/examples on how to use [Embed] metadata or 
Flash SWF files but they all tell me to either use a path in the source attrib or a text string in the systemFont attrib. What I want to do is; at runtime get all installed fonts on a given machine, determine which are TTF/OTF, embed them all and offer them in a comboBox. Something along these lines;

```
public function embedFonts():void{
    try{  
        //get all device and embedded fonts
        availableFonts = Font.enumerateFonts(true);
        availableFonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);

        for each(var thisFont:Font in availableFonts)
        {
            [Embed(systemFont=thisFont.fontName,
            fontName=thisFont.fontName,
            mimeType='application/x-font')]

            //this bit need to create a unique variable name on each loop
            var thisfont:Class;
        }
    }
    catch(error:Error){
        //if cant embed it's likely not to be TTF or OTF
        //so move on to the next font.                  
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a way?

Many, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed fonts at runtime.
And what would be the point?

Your swf runs on my machine, enumerates fonts on my machine, then embeds them
and offer them back to me? They are installed, use them directly, no need to embed.

So not only that is it not possible, but probably nobody will ever implement such a feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thinking behind this is because I'm using the ObjectHandles library so if I'm going to scale, rotate, or play with the alpha channel of text in flex, I'm must embed the font. It would be great to know which of your fonts I can use and then offer them all, rather than just a sub-set of fonts that I choose at compile time.